# how do i use the numbers i key in from a form as the input data for chartjs

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

> i am trying to use my input data as the data of the graph
> i am using chartjs
> please help
> iv tried to split and join the numbers but nothing is showing
> i am using flask as my back end

```
var Diadata = []
 function getdata() {
      Diadata[0] = document.getElementById('Carat').value;
      Diadata[1] = document.getElementById("Cut").value;
      Diadata[2] = document.getElementById("Color").value;
      Diadata[3] = document.getElementById("Clarity").value;
      Diadata[4] = document.getElementById("Depth").value;
      Diadata[5] = document.getElementById("Table").value;
      Diadata[6] = document.getElementById("X").value;
      Diadata[7] = document.getElementById("Y").value;
      Diadata[8] = document.getElementById("Z").value;
     console.log("TEST: ",[Diadata.join(" ").replace(/ /g,",")])
 }



var ctxL = document.getElementById("barChartHorizontal").getContext('2d');
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctxL, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Carat", "Cut", "Color", "Clarity", "Depth", "Table", "X", "Y", "Z"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Price",
        data: [Diadata.join(" ").replace(/ /g,",")], //i want to add my input data here
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        borderWidth: 0,
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The data array is expecting an array with values so if you remove your join it should work.

You would get this:

```
var Diadata = []
 function getdata() {
      Diadata[0] = document.getElementById('Carat').value;
      Diadata[1] = document.getElementById("Cut").value;
      Diadata[2] = document.getElementById("Color").value;
      Diadata[3] = document.getElementById("Clarity").value;
      Diadata[4] = document.getElementById("Depth").value;
      Diadata[5] = document.getElementById("Table").value;
      Diadata[6] = document.getElementById("X").value;
      Diadata[7] = document.getElementById("Y").value;
      Diadata[8] = document.getElementById("Z").value;
 }


getdata();
var ctxL = document.getElementById("barChartHorizontal").getContext('2d');
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctxL, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Carat", "Cut", "Color", "Clarity", "Depth", "Table", "X", "Y", "Z"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Price",
        data: Diadata, //i want to add my input data here
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        borderWidth: 0,
      }
    ]
  },
```